# Why is the Python readline module not available on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, readline

The documentation of the Python [`readline`](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-readline.html) module says "Availability: Unix". However, it doesn't appear to be available on OS X, although other modules marked as Unix are available. Here is what I'm using:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin greg.local 8.11.1 Darwin Kernel Version 8.11.1: Wed Oct 10 18:23:28 PDT 2007; root:xnu-792.25.20~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 i386
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.3.5 (#1, Nov 26 2007, 09:16:55) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5363) (+4864187)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import readline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in ?
ImportError: No module named readline
>>>
```

I have also installed Python 2.5 through MacPorts but `readline` is not available there either.

What can I do to provide `readline` functionality for Python's `raw_input()` function on OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to install the `py-readline` (or `py25-readline` for Python 2.5) port?

Also, in the snippet above, you are NOT using the MacPort python, but rather the Apple Python.

The MacPort version should be located in the `/opt/local` directory structure. You should check your path.

Comment: As I said, I have also installed Python 2.5 through MacPorts and readline is not available there. But installing py25-readline worked, thanks!

Comment: If you are using the MacPorts Python you might also want to install the 'python_select' package to set your default Python interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

Try `rlwrap`. It should work with any version of python and in general any shell.

Install via `brew install rlwrap` on Mac OS X

usage as `rlwrap python`. It stores history as well.

Comment: ^ Awesome solution for Mac OSX... much nicer than having to install a whole new version of Python or having to type `stty sane` when you can't even see what you're typing.

Comment: After fighting comments about xcode and 3897 things that didn't work, this finally got me a usable python shell again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's not shipped in OS X because of licensing issues (restrictions brought to you by the GPL).

Macports python should be fine if you have the readline package installed.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get readline support on Mac's native Python. Apparently it's implemented via BSD's editline, and you have to start it up slightly differently. I just tested this on a Mac, and it works fine (OS X 10.5.7). See `man python` for more details, the section "Interactive Input Editing and History Substitution" - [mirrored on the web here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html).

```
luga ~ $ python 
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rlcompleter
>>> import readline
>>>
```

Comment: If you want to automate this, put the import lines in a file called (for example) .pythonrc and put it in your home directory. Add a line "export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc" to your .bashrc and voila. For vi keybindings, create .editrc in your home directory, and add the line "bind -v".