# Configuring up and down arrows to scroll history in Python shell

Tags: python

I installed Python 2.7 on my mac from source. Before, I could use the arrow keys to scroll through my history. Now, I get this:

```
>>> print 'stupid'
'stupid'
>>> ^[[A # This is my feeble attempt at scrolling up.
```

Scrolling still works if I use Python 2.6

Is there a config file for this or is this something that I have to set at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [forgot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327251/why-is-the-python-readline-module-not-available-on-os-x) to install readline or libedit before building.

Comment: Ah, that works. Homebrew uses readline when compiling Python.